# Matlab :Continuous Convolution and plotting

Tags: matlab, for-loop, plot, convolution

I would like to compute  circular convolution of Input Concentration values with Output concentration equation and plot  accordingly, following are my functions

The function for Input Concentration is computed as follows and the plot of Concentration Vs time is plotted

```
function c = Input_function(t, a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, td, tmax)



c = zeros(size(t));

ind = (t > td) & (t < tmax);
c(ind) = (t(ind) - td) ./ (tmax - td) * (a1 + a2 + a3);


ind = (t >= tmax);
c(ind) = a1 * exp(-b1 * (t(ind) - tmax))+ a2 * exp(-b2 * (t(ind) - tmax)) + a3 * exp(-b3   * (t(ind) - tmax));





plot(t, c);
%plot(t,c_t);
hold all;


axis([-100 5000 -2000 80000]);
xlabel time ;
ylabel concentration ;

end
```

Now i would like to compute the convolution of the above function with following equation.

```
C_tot = ((k1*k2)/(k2+k3))*exp(-(k2+k3)*t) + (k1*k3)/(k2+k3)
```

where C_tot represents Output equation.

Basically i have to computed the Convolution of

```
C_tot and C(ind) at (t > td) & (t < tmax)

C_tot and C(ind) at (t >= tmax)
```

and plot the them accordingly, kindly let me know how shall i proceed this problem in matlab, the values K1,K2 K3 are user defined

Comment: @patrik Not sure, if it works,but can you tell me how i can use cconv on both functions

Comment: cconv calculates the circular convolution of modolus N, try `a = [2 1 2 1]; b = [1 2 3 4]; c = cconv(a,b,4)` for more info see the help on the function

Comment: To see the help, type: `help cconv`

Comment: Sure but you can get more help on mathworks homepage by typing cconv matlab on google, which is probably more convenient, if you do not already konw the function before

Comment: I have tried cconv but its of no use, this is my problem